# Batch job definition: How to run a dynamically-calculated number of partitions?

Tags: jsr352, java-batch

As a newbie to the Batch Processing API (JSR-352), I have some difficulties modeling the following (simplified) scenario:

1. Suppose we have a `Batchlet` that produces a dynamic set of files in a first `step`.
2. In a second `step`, all these files must be processed individually in `chunk`s (via `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor` and `ItemWriter`) resulting in a new set of files.
3. In a third `step` these new files need to be packaged in one large archive.

I couldn't find a way to define the second step because the specification doesn't seem to provide a loop construct (and in my understanding `partition`, `split` and `flow` only work for a set with a known fixed size).

How could a job xml definition look like? Do I have to give up on the idea of chunking in the second step or do I have to divide the task into multiple jobs? Is there another option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **[PartitionMapper](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/batch/1.0/apidocs/javax/batch/api/partition/PartitionMapper.html)** to programmatically define a dynamic number of partitions for a partitioned step.

The mapper needs to create a **PartitionPlan** object which sets the number of partitions and provides partition-specific properties for each.

Your mapper's **mapPartitions()** method will look something like this outline:

```
public PartitionPlan mapPartitions() throws Exception {

    int numPartitions = // calculate number of partitions, however you want

    // create an array of Properties objects, one for each partition
    Properties[] props = new Properties[numPartitions];

    for (int i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++) {
        // create a Properties object for this partition
        props[i] = new Properties();

        props[i].setProperty("abc", ...);
        props[i].setProperty("xyz", ...);
    }

    // use the built-in PartitionPlanImpl from the spec or your own impl
    PartitionPlan partitionPlan = new PartitionPlanImpl(); 
    partitionPlan.setPartitions(numPartitions);

    // cet the Properties[] onto your plan
    partitionPlan.setPartitionProperties(props);

    return partitionPlan;
}
```

And then you can reference the partition-specific property values in substitution like this (which is the same way you reference statically-defined partition properties):

```
    <batchlet ref="myBatchlet">
        <properties>
            <property name="propABC" value="#{partitionPlan['abc']}" />
            <property name="propXYZ" value="#{partitionPlan['xyz']}" />
        </properties>
    </batchlet>
```

Comment: Great, I'll try to put this together and will report back.

Comment: Ok, after a little experiment I am now ready to see how this might work for us. My PartitionMapper implementation returns one property per partition, which contains the respective filename. Instead of the shown batchlet, I use a chunk. Its ItemReader, ItemProcessor, and ItemWriter are called in multiple iterations (for each partition). They can read the filename property and act independently. -- Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help.  I'm thinking of editing the question description to make it more clearly associated with "how to run a dynamically-calculated number of partitions?"

Comment: In terms of future reference, this would make quite sense.

Comment: Suppose , I have two numPartitions  like variables or 2 array lists to be partitioned, can I do this in the same mapPartitions() method?

Comment: Shubhro, I'm not understanding your question.  Can you ask a new question with your code example?